# Proof of the description of a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We are supposed to describe the set $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ with a proof.

$A_n = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | y-x^{2n} \geq 0 \}$.

This is what I have so far: "This is just the set of all points above the graph $y=x^2$, $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, in addition to all the points where $-1\leq x \leq 1$ and $y\geq 0$. When you plot it, it looks like that. ", but I am not sure how to prove it. I had just plotted the parabolas and assumed that this was true.

Comment: To prove set equality you should show that each element in one set exists in the other and vice versa

Answer (score 1):

Divide the real plane into $N = \{(x, y): -1 < x < 1\}$ and $F = \mathbb{R}^2 - N$, where N stands for *"near y axis"* and F stands for *"far from y axis"*.

1. Show that $\bigcup A_n = \bigcup (A_n \cap N) \cup \bigcup (A_n \cap F)$.
2. Show that $A_n \cap F \supset A_{n+1} \cap F$ and thus $\bigcup (A_n \cap F) = A_1 \cap F$
3. Show that $A_n \cap N \subset A_{n+1} \cap N$ and thus $\bigcup (A_n \cap N) = \{(x,y):y>0 \vee x=y=0\} \cap N$

Comment: Your third step is incorrect: the point $(1,0)$ is not contained in any $A_n$.

Comment: @Strants, you're right. Should be fixed now.

Comment: @KarolisJuodele I hate to be nitpicky, but for any nonzero $x$, $x^{2n} > 0$, so the only point $(x,0)$ which can be contained in the union is $x = 0$.  (I should have been more clear in my first post, sorry).

Comment: @Strants, oh my, that's a lot of errors to make in a short answer. Thanks for pointing them out.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a formal or complete proof: I'll leave it to you to fill in the details.

There are three cases: $|x| \ge 1$ $0 < |x| < 1$, and $x = 0$.

If $|x| > 1$, then $x^2 \le x^{2n}$ for any $n = 1, 2, \ldots$, so any point in $A_n$ which is outside of the strip $|x| \le 1$ is also contained in $A_1$.

If $0 < |x| < 1$, then $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}x^{2n} = 0$, so for $n$ large enough, $x^{2n}$ can be made less than any positive real number $y$. But, notice that $x^{2n} > 0$ for any $n$.

If $x = 0$, then $y - x^{2n} \ge 0$ means $\ldots$?